# Keep form data if reCAPTCHA fails

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have three quick questions that I hope someone can help with:

1) I am trying to make my form keep it's data when the user fails the reCAPTCHA test. How can I do that? My existing code is below.

2) From other similar StackOverFlow questions, someone suggested using:

```
value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['first_name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name']) : ''); ?>
```

which seems to keep the data for all the fields EXCEPT the message field which is obviously the most important:) For the message field, I tried using the following with no success:

```
    value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['message']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']) : ''); ?>
```

3) Lastly, is the above code safe to use if it works? I know that user submission forms can be a serious security threat.

Here is my existing code:

```
<?php
$mail =  get_field('email');
$title = get_the_title();

if(isset(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)['submit'])){

// check reCAPTCHA information
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');

    $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
              $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
              filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
              filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    // if CAPTCHA is correctly entered!                       
    if ($resp->is_valid) {          

$to = $mail; // this is your Email address
$from = trim(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)['email']); // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = trim(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)['first_name']);
$last_name = trim(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)['last_name']);
$contact_number = trim(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)['contact_number']);
$subject = "Website enquiry";
$subject2 = "Website automated message";
$message ="Message";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly." . "<br/><br/>";
} else {
        // handle the CAPTCHA being entered incorrectly
        echo "Sorry,  you entered the reCAPTCHA code incorrectly.";
        $_SESSION['form'] = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    }
}
?>

<form action= "#contact-form" method="post">
First Name:<br> <input type="text" name="first_name" ><br>
Last Name:<br> <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Contact Number:<br> <input type="text" name="contact_number"><br>
Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<p>Are you a human? Please enter the text in the image below.</p>
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A `textarea` doesn't have a `value` attribute. The `value` goes between the opening and closing tag.

Comment: So how would i be able then to store the message data?

Comment: `<textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"><?php echo $_POST['message']?></textarea>` should work.

Answer (score -1):

A `textarea` doesn't have a `value` attribute. Instead you need to place what is in `$_POST['message']` between the opening and closing tag:

```
<textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Please stop introducing XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you referring to using something like `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)` instead of `$_POST`?